# Apk App not installed

Tags: parsing, apk, apktool

today I was editing and apk (A modified kik client) on the apktool known as "advanced apktool." I edited a couple different apk apps to test after I received my problem, to see if it was just the apk. It wasn't. After I decompiled and edited the app, I recompiled, signed the package, and dragged the finished product to my dropbox. I went to download it on my android when I got the error"application not installed". My friend could not install either as he got a "error parsing package" error. I then tried zip aligning and downloading, still no luck. I don't know why I cannot download it. I have no other interfering package names. I tried it with and without the original app. It did not work. I believe it the way I saved, or maybe the signing key. It is not my phone, as my friend could also not download it. Thank you for reading, please ask if you need clarification.

Comment: I think you properly sign your apk

Comment: What do you mean? I believe I signed the package correctly, yes.

Comment: Try this..https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/install/

Comment: Thank you! I used this to create my app, then a .jar called apk-signer_1.8.5 to sign it and it worked. :D